# SQL update Table B with last column from table A

Tags: sql-server

Version of SQL: Microsoft SQL Server 2019

I try to create an update command to update Category from table `City` to `City_category` based on all columns from City. In case the names are duplicated I need to assign to first come up base on columns.

My Bad code example:

```
Update B 
Set    B.Category = A.category
From   City A Inner Join City_category B
          On B.Cityname = A.Cityname1 or
          B.Cityname = A.Cityname2 or
          B.Cityname =A.Cityname3
```

If I select what I try to update I got duplicated value "Arrah" =(

```
Select B.Cityname = A.category 
From City A
Inner Join City_category B
On B.Cityname = A.Cityname1 or
   B.Cityname = A.Cityname2 or
   B.Cityname =A.Cityname3
```

Table example:

```
CREATE TABLE City( 
   Cityname1 nvarchar (20) NULL,
   Cityname2 nvarchar (20) NULL,
   Cityname3 nvarchar (20) NULL,
   Category  nvarchar (20) NULL
)

INSERT INTO City 
VALUES
('Dailing','Sukamanah','Songmuping','LTT'),
('Buenavista','Barajevo','Gryaznovskoye','OPN'),
('Lazaro','Paris','Arrah','IOM'),
('Rungis','Arrah','Santa','MD2');

CREATE TABLE City_category(
   Cityname nvarchar 20 NULL,
   Category nvarchar 20 NULL
)

INSERT INTO City_category (Cityname)
VALUES
   ('Dailing'),
   ('Gryaznovskoye'),
   ('Paris'),
   ('Arrah');
```

Result: **City_category**

| Cityname | Category |
| --- | --- |
| Dailing | LTT |
| Gryaznovskoye | OPN |
| Paris | IOM |
| Arrah | MD2 |

Thank you for your help in advance =)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Hello Yitzhak Khabinsky
Sorry for the confusion.
I update my post hope this could help you to understand what i try to achive.
the problem citys allways come random and category =( i can not hardcode this

Comment: Guess this is one of the disadvantages of a de-normalized structure. There might be slicker options, but why do you insist on doing it with a single UPDATE? Executing separate updates, one for each "city", would work as expected https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6eae08cab928858625921f94955deee0